# How to fetch a value as a string in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, string, collections

I have one database query which returns collection, i want to fetch the value instead of fetching `collection` or `array`, please help me to achieve this  thing

```
$type=DB::table('users')->where('id',$value)->pluck('role')->toArray();
```

**Actual Result** : ['admin']          //array

**Expected Result** : $type='admin'

Comment: Why would you expect `$type` to be in the result, where does that come from? `->toArray()` returns ... an array, have you tried echoing its first(only) element?

Comment: `->toArray()[0]` I presume.

Comment: @brombeer, first() returns string, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use implode...

```
implode("|",$type);
```